# catch exception in outer try/except

Tags: python, python-2.7, try-except

In the following code,

```
def func():
    try:
        try:                           # No changes to be made here
            x = 2/0                    # No changes to be made here
        except ZeroDivisionError:      # No changes to be made here
            print "Division by zero is not possible"     # No changes to be made here
    except:
        raise Exception("Exception caught")

func()
```

Is there a way to let the outer try/except block raise the exception without making any changes to the inner try/except?

Comment: No, there isn't, but you _could_ do what ettanany suggest.

Comment: Exception got caught inside - so why should you want this? otherwise throw a new/same one in the inner catch-block. I Guess @ettanany got your question/solution. but there is no way like you asked for it.

Comment: you can use raise in if, else and def!

Comment: The problem here is that the inner exception block is handling the exception and not reraising it. If you add a simple `raise` to the inner exception handler at the end you will get the desired behaviour. Once an exception is handled and not further raised there is no way to propagate is as you want. Why would you want to propagate an exception that was already solved?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like what you actually want to do is catch an exception raised by another function.  To do that you need to raise an exception from the function (i.e. inner try/except in the example).

```
def func1():
    try:
        x = 2/0
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print "Division by zero is not possible" 
        raise

def func2():
    try:
        func1()
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print "Exception caught"

func2()
# Division by zero is not possible
# Exception caught
```

Notice that I've made two crucial changes.  1) I've re-raised the error within the inner function. and 2) I've caught the specific exception in the second function.